# How to publish layer on geoserver using rest api with PHP CURL

Tags: geoserver, php, curl

I'm working in a project that I need to publish a layer automatically on geoserver. Searching I discover that the REST API can help me. Studying the REST API I saw that I need to use cURL to do that(the only example there), but I need the FILE FORMAT SHP and try to do a script with the cURL comands:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file:///home/Test_data/public_html/BRN_GIS/Shape_files/Links.shp" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/BRN/datastores/Roads/external.shp
```

and php code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/BRN/datastores/Roads/external.shp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:geoserver"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
$data="file:///home/Test_data/public_html/BRN_GIS/Shape_files/Roads.shp";
if ($data != '') {
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
     array("Content-Type: text/plain",
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($data))
     );
 }
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   $rslt = curl_exec($ch);
   $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
   echo $rslt;
```